# How to use Android Studio on AMD without HAXM installed?

Tags: android, ios, dart, error-handling, haxm

My Computer is based on AMD processor.
Im working with Android Visual Studio to develop an app with flutter. But when i try to run a virtual device it dosen´t work, because of HAXM.

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. HAXM is not installed.

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Because i am using AMD cpu and don´t own Windows 10 pro license.
There was no other way than to buy an intel processor or to buy windows 10 pro.
That's why i decided to upgrade windows, now it is working with Hyper-V...

Comment: You could have used Bluestacks.

Answer (score 1):

Emulators on machines with an AMD processor have been supported since July 2018 as stated in [Android Emulator - AMD Processor & Hyper-V Support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html).

In addition to that, there is a [guide on developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#requirements) for setting up an emulator in various environments with details on system requirements:

> - SDK Tools 26.1.1 or higher
> - 64-bit processor
> - Windows: CPU with UG (unrestricted guest) support
> - HAXM 6.2.1 or later (HAXM 7.2.0 or later recommended)
>
> The use of [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration) has additional requirements on
>   Windows and Linux:
>
> - Intel processor on Windows or Linux: Intel processor with support for Intel VT-x, Intel EM64T (Intel 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
> - AMD processor on Linux: AMD processor with support for AMD Virtualization (AMD-V) and [Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3)
>     (SSSE3)
> - AMD processor on Windows: Android Studio 3.2 or higher and Windows 10 April 2018 release or higher for [Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/)
>     functionality
>
> To work with Android 8.1 (API level 27) and higher system images, an
>   attached webcam must have the capability to capture 720p frames.

So it seems that you have to make sure your development machine has the required features and then follow the steps from the blog post.